# Search a MySQL table using multiple fields

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, request, laravel-5

I have this HTML form which has so many fields that someone can use to query data from MySQL table using multiple conditions. The form has select boxes, text boxes and check boxes, and date inputs.

[image: search]

I have this function which is ineffective

```
public function search(Request $request)
    {

        // loop through the defined fields
        foreach($this->fields as $field){
            // if the field is set and not empty
            if(is_array($request->get($field))){
                foreach ($request->get($field) as $value) {
                    $this->conditions[] = "`$field` = '" . $value . "'";
                }
            } else {
                 if(isset($_POST[$field]) && $request->get($field) != '') {

                    $data = $request->get($field);

                    if($field == 'bf_ref_no'){
                        $data = is_numeric( substr($request->get($field), 0, 2) )  ? 'BF'.$request->get($field)  : $request->get($field) ;
                    }

                    $this->conditions[] = "`$field` = '" . $data . "'";
                }
            }

        }

        // builds the query
        $query = "SELECT invoices.id as inv_id, invoices.created_at as inv_date, invoices.amount_paid, invoices.amount, csv_data_final.* FROM csv_data_final 
        LEFT JOIN invoices ON invoices.parent_id = csv_data_final.id ";
        // if there are conditions defined
        if(count($this->conditions) > 0) {
            // append the conditions
            $query .= "WHERE " . implode (' AND ', $this->conditions); // you can change to 'OR', but I suggest to apply the filters cumulative
        }

        $results = DB::select( $query );

        $borders = DB::table('borders')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();

        return view('track.track-withdata', compact('results', 'borders'));

    }
```

This code doesn't work for dates using BETWEEN keyword.

Comment: Please run your code, echo out what $query is after implode, **publish it**, show some **sample data** in a SQLFIDDLE, then we have a chance to help

Comment: As far as I can see, you didn't even try include any special case for your date fields to use `BETWEEN`. Give it a try, and if it doesn't work - post us your sample code so we'll be able to give a hand.